# Is there a way to create Javascript filter with radio buttons and checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, filter, fetch

I have this task that has to been done soon, I have been trying to figure it out for the past couple of days but unfortunately, I have failed every time. I need to create a filter, where the user can click on a radio button to get those specific courses, after that or even before, he can click on checkboxes to filter even further.

I have managed to go through the "first" part of the filtering with radio buttons, the biggest issue is that I can't filter with checkboxes because for example -> you can't choose 2 options from the checkboxes.

Here is HTML

```
                    By subject:<br>
                    <form action="">
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Computing & IT">Computing & IT</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Psychology & Sociology">Psychology & Sociology</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Business & Management">Business & Management</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Law & Criminology">Law & Criminology</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Data Analytics">Data Analytics</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Finance">Finance</input><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="name" value="Human Resource Management">Human Resource Management</input><br>
                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                    </form>
                    <hr>
                    <h4> By Award:</h4>
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Postgraduate">Postgraduate</input><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Undergraduate">Undergraduate</input><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Top-Up">Top-Up</input><br>
                    </form>
```

and here is JS

```
fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axsrs")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data =>  {
    let api_array = data.name;
    let radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
    api_array.map(item => {
        document.getElementById('app').innerHTML +=
        `<div class="card">
        <h6>${item.vertical}</h6>
        <h4>${item.program}</h4>
        <p>${item.level}</p>
        <button class="myButton">Enquire Now</button>
        `
    })
    for(let select of radio) {
        select.addEventListener('click',() => {
            document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = "";
            let api_array = data.name.filter(e => e.vertical === select.value)
            api_array.map(item => {
                document.getElementById('app').innerHTML +=
                `<div class="card">
                <h6>${item.vertical}</h6>
                <h4>${item.program}</h4>
                <p>${item.level}</p>
                <button class="myButton">Enquire Now</button>
                `
            })
            for(let check of checkboxes) {
                check.addEventListener('change',() => {
                    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = "";
                    if(check.checked) {
                    let chosen = api_array.filter(c => c.level === check.value)
                    chosen.map(item => {
                        document.getElementById('app').innerHTML +=
                        `<div class="card">
                        <h6>${item.vertical}</h6>
                        <h4>${item.program}</h4>
                        <p>${item.level}</p>
                        <button class="myButton">Enquire Now</button>
                        `
                    })
                    } else {
                    }
                }) 
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the exact problem and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like that users can filter through the list of the things inside of the API with the radio buttons and checkboxes, the problem is that the radio buttons are working but you cant filter with 2 checkboxes.